# Why does 'for anytext; do' loop four times?

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

Is this a bug or a feature?
It seems to happen for *unquoted* alphanumerics.

Running GNU bash, version 4.1.5

```
for alpha01234; do echo $((++i)); done
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is a feature of the `for` compound command, as described by `help for`:

> `for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done`
>
> Execute commands for each member in a list.
>
> The `for` loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
>   list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;` is not present, then `in "$@"` is
>   assumed.  For each element in `WORDS`, `NAME` is set to that element, and
>   the `COMMANDS` are executed.

So the code you quoted is probably executed in a script which was called with 4 parameters.

Comment: Thanks... The thing that threw me completely was that it happened at the command line..  I actually didn't try it in a script..  I must have used `set a b c d` at some time recently. I often use `set` that way in a script for testing..  After restarting the terminal, it has stopped... (makes sense now)..

Answer (score 12):

`for x; do …` is a shortcut for `for x in "$@"; do …`: it iterates over the positional parameters. If it loops four times, it means you have four positional parameters (`$1` through `$4`).